# Split from one specific word to another specific word

Tags: c#, regex

Assuming a string like `Foo: Some Text Bar: Some Other Text FooBar: Even More Text` and a goal to have it split into:

```
Foo: Some Text
Bar: Some Other Text
FooBar: Even More Text
```

I can't figure out the Regex for it at all. I can split it based on the words I want like `(Foo:)|(Bar:)|(FooBar:)` but I can't figure out how to include from the beginning of each group to the beginning of the next group (or end of text if last group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Split` to split the string with

```
(?<!^)\s+(?=\b(?:Bar|Foo(?:Bar)?):)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5E%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3D%5Cb%28%3F%3ABar%7CFoo%28%3F%3ABar%29%3F%29%3A%29&i=Foo%3A%20Some%20Text%20Bar%3A%20Some%20Other%20Text%20FooBar%3A%20Even%20More%20Text). Details:

- `(?<!^)` - not at the start of string
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(?=\b(?:Bar|Foo(?:Bar)?):)`  - immediately to the right, there must be

  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(?:Bar|Foo(?:Bar)?)` - `Bar`, `Foo` or `FooBar`
  - `:` - a colon.

C# demo:

```cs
var s = "Foo: Some Text Bar: Some Other Text FooBar: Even More Text";
var res = Regex.Split(s, @"(?<!^)\s+(?=\b(?:Bar|Foo(?:Bar)?):)");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", res));
```

Output:

```cs
Foo: Some Text
Bar: Some Other Text
FooBar: Even More Text
```

**Another idea**: matching any word before a colon and all up to the next word with a `:` after:

```cs
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"\w+(?:-\w+)*:.*?(?=\s*(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*:|$))", RegexOptions.Singleline)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cw%2b%28%3f%3a-%5cw%2b%29*%3a.*%3f%28%3f%3d%5cs*%28%3f%3a%5cw%2b%28%3f%3a-%5cw%2b%29*%3a%7c%24%29%29&i=Foo%3a+Some+Text+Bar%3a+Some+Other+Text+FooBar%3a+Even+More+Text).

**Details**

- `\w+(?:-\w+)*:` - 1 or more word chars (letters/digits/underscores), and then 0 or more repetitions of `-` and 1+ word chars
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s+(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*:|$))` - up to the first occurrence of

  - `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces

    - `(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*:` - either 1 or more word chars (letters/digits/underscores), and then 0 or more repetitions of `-` and 1+ word chars and then a colon
  - `|` - or

    - `$` - end of string
  - `)`

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/b4GRWF).

Comment: `\w+:.*?(?=\s+\w+:|$)` almost gets me what I need. Let me play around with this. Thanks for the detailed explanation of what each magic thing does. Regex really is wizardry. Thanks.

Comment: Can I modify my question to slightly better match my real example. It's just changing the words from `Foo: Bar: FooBar:` to `Foo: Bar: Foo-Bar:`?

Comment: @gilliduck It will be almost the same. `\w+(?:-\w+)?:.*?(?=\s+\w+(?:-\w+)?:|$)` or `\w+(?:-\w+)*:.*?(?=\s+\w+(?:-\w+)*:|$)`

Comment: That's perfect. It matches exactly for me. Thank you!